# Group by causes 500 internel server error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, left-join, inner-join

I've made a webapplication , tested it on localhost works perfectly. Put it on my server and on a `GROUP BY` in a query it outputs an empty screen with an `500 internal server error` in the console.

```
  $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT users.username FROM users INNER JOIN questions ON users.question_id=questions.id  WHERE questions.question_list_pass = "'.$ww.'" GROUP BY users.username ORDER BY users.username');
  $sth->execute();
  $usernames = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT questions.id, questions.question_name FROM 
questions INNER JOIN users ON users.question_id=questions.id WHERE questions.question_list_pass = "'.$ww.'" GROUP BY questions.question_name ORDER BY questions.question_name');
  $sth->execute();
  $question_names = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The first query is identical to the second exept for getting data from different tables. When I run the script it outputs a `500 internal server error` and when I *remove* the `GROUP BY questions.question_name` from the second query (but still keep the order by) the script works BUT it outputs everything multiple times (because the order by won't work properly)

Any ideas how this is possible? I've let different people look at it but nobody has a clue what's incorrect.

With kind regards,

Comment: Why do you need the join in the first place?  Doesn't seem like you need anything from users in the 2nd query unless it's to limit questions associated to users.... which a exists would do more efficiently. Why do you need a group by if you have no aggregation?  GROUP BY is really only needed if you have aggregation.  If you have duplicate questions and want distinct records, use DISTINCT. `SELECT DISTINCT questions.id, questions.question_name FROM 
questions INNER JOIN users ON users.question_id=questions.id WHERE questions.question_list_pass = "'.$ww.'" ORDER BY questions.question_name`

Comment: 500 internal error cause `$sth = false`. So you have fatal error when you do `execute();`. Please coment the exec and fetch all and past your query string

`echo 'SELECT users.username FROM users INNER JOIN questions ON users.question_id=questions.id  WHERE questions.question_list_pass = "'.$ww.'" GROUP BY users.username ORDER BY users.username'`;

Comment: If you check your error logs you'll get a pretty good explanation usually.

Comment: I am speculating that you are using MySQL, so I added the tag.

Comment: Get rid of the GROUP BY clause. Problem solved. If you want DISTINCT results, use DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a group by if you have no aggregation?  `GROUP BY` is really only needed if you have aggregation.

Why do you need the join in the first place?  The join itself seems to be causing the record duplication so by eliminating it we get rid of the need for distinct.  It doesn't seem like you need anything from users in the 2nd query unless it's to limit questions associated to users.... which a exists would do more efficiently.

If you have duplicate questions/results and want distinct records, use `DISTINCT`.

This use of an exists though a correlated sub query seems like it would be more efficient eliminating the join which is causing the apparent duplication.  You could just add a distinct, but this just seems... cleaner...  Now, if you have additional where clause criteria specific to a user, or need to display user information in the results as well; then a distinct would likely make more sense.

```
SELECT Q.id, Q.question_name 
FROM questions Q
WHERE Q.question_list_pass = "'.$ww.'" 
  and exists (SELECT 1
              FROM users U 
              WHERE U.Question_ID = Q.Questions_ID)
ORDER BY Q.question_name`
```